# SELECT from multiple tables - duplicate data

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to retrieve some data from across 2 MySQL tables and I'm having a little issue preventing multiples of the same data from appearing in the query.

What I've got is a system where a user is able to register an account, and then register multiple devices into that account. For each device, they can submit data from each of my applications. This data will have a unique ID that's specific to that device (`DATA_GUID` in the Table_Data table below) -- this allows me to update the data for a specific application running on a specific device simply by calculating the data GUID (which is calculated from device ID and source application).

**See edit below for a visual description**

Here's my table setup;

**Table_Devices**

- DEV_GUID *(A unique device ID)*
- API_ID *(A unique account ID - used to see which account the device belongs to)*
- DEVICE_FRIENDLY_NAME *(A 'friendly name' that the user can use to identify the device)*
- DEVICE_PLATFORM *(Device platform)*
- DEVICE_MODEL *(Device model)*

**Table_Data**

- DATA_GUID *(A unique ID related to the specific applications data for a specific device)*
- SOURCE_APPLICATION *(The application which submitted the data related to DATA GUID)*

What I'm trying to achieve is to get a list of an individual device details (i.e. GUID, Friendly name, platform, model) and each `DATA_GUID` associated with that device (along with the `SOURCE_APPLICATION` it was submitted from), based upon the API_ID that I submit.

I tried this query (value at the end obviously contained a valid `API_ID`);

```
SELECT
a.DEV_GUID, a.DEVICE_FRIENDLY_NAME, a.DEVICE_PLATFORM, a.DEV_MODEL,
b.DATA_GUID, b.SOURCE_APPLICATION
FROM Table_Devices a
INNER JOIN
Table_Data b
WHERE a.API_ID = "value"
```

Unfortunately that returns every possible combination of data, device, etc. instead of returning only data that is associated with a specific `API_ID`.

Where am I going wrong?

---

**Edit**

I think I might have confused a few people, so here's a few extra pieces that might help out.

[image]

As you can see, the DATA_GUID for each application is different on an individual device but also is different compared to the same app on other devices. For example, **App 0 on Device 0** for this account has a different DATA_GUID to **App 1 on Device 0**, or **App 0 on Device 1** for example.

Using the example above (along with the original information provided), how would I retrieve the device information (from **TABLE_DEVICES**) and SOURCE_APPLICATION and DATA_GUID (from **TABLE_DATA**) based upon a provided Table_Devices.API_ID (represented in the picture as equivalent of 'ACC0')?

The results I might expect back;

```
 | DEV_GUID | SOURCE_APPLICATION | DATA_GUID  | API_ID |
 -------------------------------------------------------
 | DEV0     | APP0               | ACC0_D0_A0 | ACC0   |
 | DEV0     | APP1               | ACC0_D0_A1 | ACC0   |
 | DEV0     | APP2               | ACC0_D0_A2 | ACC0   |
 | DEV1     | APP0               | ACC0_D1_A0 | ACC0   |
 | DEV1     | APP1               | ACC0_D1_A1 | ACC0   |
 | DEV1     | APP2               | ACC0_D1_A2 | ACC0   |
 | DEV2     | APP0               | ACC0_D2_A0 | ACC0   |
 | DEV2     | APP1               | ACC0_D2_A1 | ACC0   |
 | DEV2     | APP2               | ACC0_D2_A2 | ACC0   |
 -------------------------------------------------------
```

The results I ACTUALLY get back were every combination of the details, so for example it might show something like this for one of the rows;

```
 | DEV_GUID | SOURCE_APPLICATION | DATA_GUID  | API_ID |
 -------------------------------------------------------
 | DEV1     | APP2               | ACC0_D0_A1 | ACC0   |
 -------------------------------------------------------
```

Obviously `ACC0_D0_A1`, though it is valid for that account, isn't valid for APP2 running on DEV1. I'm trying to achieve something along the lines of what's shown in the first psuedo-result table (where the data for each row is *strictly correct* so to speak) but obviously including the extra fields listed in the original request.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
a.DEV_GUID, a.DEVICE_FRIENDLY_NAME, a.DEVICE_PLATFORM, a.DEV_MODEL,
b.DATA_GUID, b.SOURCE_APPLICATION
FROM Table_Devices a
INNER JOIN
Table_Data b
WHERE a.API_ID = "value" AND a.DEV_GUID = b.DATA_GUID
```

Comment: To associate and restrict the projection (which is the SELECT) to the selection (which is the WHERE, funny, isn't it, but that's just because the SELECT chooses which fields to contain in your data whilst the WHERE selects which data records should be contained in your result set)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify how b joins to a as otherwise MySQL can only assume that every row in a joins to every row in b, as you are currently seeing.  You have stated that a.DEV_GUID = b.DATA_GUID and so the following ON criteria would be optimal.

I would say that re-selecting b.DATA_GUID is pointless though because it equals a.DEV_GUID, giving the following.

Finally you were after all source applications.  To do this you need to make use of GROUP functions, i.e.

```
SELECT
    a.DEV_GUID, 
    a.DEVICE_FRIENDLY_NAME, 
    a.DEVICE_PLATFORM, 
    a.DEV_MODEL,
    GROU_CONCAT(b.SOURCE_APPLICATION) AS SOURCE_APPLICATIONS
FROM Table_Devices a
INNER JOIN Table_Data b
    ON b.DATA_GUID = a.DEV_GUID
WHERE a.API_ID = "value"
GROUP BY a.DEV_GUID
```

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL's "where not" like this.

```
select DEV_GUID,second,third from TABLE_NAME1 where not exists (select * from SECOND_TABLE where DEV_GUID=TABLE_NAME1.DEV_GUID);
```

I always use "where not" instead of "inner join".